# Copy File Name to New File

Tags: powershell

I have a file  that contains the date it was created in the file name:

```
2456Backup20150615.txt
```

I would like to be able to grab that file name and create a new blank text file with the same name and add the extension `.pgp.trg`:

```
2456Backup20150615.txt.pgp.trg
```

Is there anyway that that can be done in PowerShell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Get-ChildItem` and `Where-Object` to find the relevant files, pipe them to `ForEach-Object` and create a new file with `New-Item`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt |Where-Object {$_.Name -match "\d{4}Backup\d{8}.txt"} |Foreach-Object { 
    New-Item "$($_.Name).pgp.trg" -ItemType File
}
```